# How to get a Weibo feed to show up in Facebook (for free)?

Tags: facebook, rss, weibo

I'm about to go to China for a few weeks, and would like to have my Facebook friends see my  updates and photo postings. Facebook and other western social networks are blocked in China, so I had an idea to create an account on Weibo.com, the "Chinese Twitter".

Now, I'm looking for a tool like [Twitterfeed](http://twitterfeed.com/), but so I can connect my Weibo to Facebook. I don't need Facebook to go to Weibo, just Weibo to Facebook. I realize it's "write only" from my perspective in China, but that's OK.

I searched for RSS feeds from Weibo, but didn't find anything useful. [IFTTT has some recipe for Weibo > Facebook](https://ifttt.com/recipes/35834), but the "Sina microblogging RSS generator" it links to seems to be a pay service.

Comment: Curiously, Instagram was not blocked when I was in China (Dec'12-Jan'13). This was how I shared the photos to facebook. Other things that don't work: Google+ (mostly because Picasa is blocked) as well as Google Drive. I read that Google Drive was blocked the day it went online, with rumors of China blocking it to protect Chinese cloud services.

Answer (score -1):

FaWave does exactly what you needed, and I'm using the same.
http://techrice.com/2011/06/03/fawave-the-easiest-way-to-post-to-twitter-and-sina-weibo-simultaneously/

Comment: FaWave requires a VPN to post to western social media sites. If I had a VPN, I wouldn't need to ask the question. I could post to Facebook directly. VPNs cost money but Weibo does not.